# Chapter name disappears for cyrillic and font changes for latin

Tags: chapters, reledpar, parallel-texts

I am trying to make a bilingual book Russian-English with a reledpar/reledmac environment. I encounter the problem where Chapter names disappear starting from the second chapter for a russian translation, whereas the font used for English chapters changes.

```
\documentclass[draft]{book}
%% Additional note from LLT: you don't need fontspec or xelatex for reledmac or reledpar to work. However, if your document _does_ involve different languages with different scripts/fonts (e.g. English and Greek or Arabic etc), then it's a good idea to use those packages -- see https://www.overleaf.com/read/wfdxqhcyyjxz for an example
%
\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english,russian, french]{babel}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage[a4paper, landscape, left=1in, right=1in, bottom=1.5in, top=1in]{geometry} %, showframe]
\usepackage[series={},nocritical,noend,noeledsec,nofamiliar,noledgroup]{reledmac}

\usepackage{reledpar}
\usepackage{epigraph}

\setlength\epigraphwidth{.3\textwidth}
\setlength\epigraphrule{0pt}

\usepackage{comment}        

\usepackage[parfill]{parskip}
\setlength{\parskip}{1ex}
\setlength{\parindent}{1ex}

\setgoalfraction{0.8}
\numberlinefalse
\begin{document}   
\begin{sloppypar}

\begin{pairs}
    \begin{Leftside}
    \selectlanguage{russian}
        \beginnumbering
            \pstart[
            \chapter*{ИСТОРИЯ ПЕРВАЯ}
            \section*{Суета Вокруг Дивана}
            \subsection*{Глава первая}]
            \epigraph{\itshape 
            Учитель: Дети, запишите предложение: «Рыба сидела на дереве». 
            \newline 
            Ученик: А разве рыбы сидят на деревьях? 
            \newline 
            Учитель: Ну... Это была сумасшедшая рыба. }{Школьный анекдот}
            \pend
            \pstart
            Я приближался к месту моего назначения. Вокруг меня, прижимаясь к самой дороге, зеленел лес, изредка уступая место полянам, поросшим желтой осокою. Солнце садилось уже который час, все никак не могло сесть и висело низко над горизонтом. Машина катилась по узкой дороге, засыпанной хрустящим гравием. Крупные камни я пускал под колесо, и каждый раз в багажнике лязгали и громыхали пустые канистры.
            \pend
            \pstart
            Справа из леса вышли двое, ступили на обочину и остановились, глядя в мою сторону. Один из них поднял руку. Я сбросил газ, их рассматривая. Это были, как мне показалось, охотники, молодые люди, может быть, немного старше меня. Их лица понравились мне, и я остановился. Тот, что поднимал руку, просунул в машину смуглое горбоносое лицо и спросил, улыбаясь:
            \pend
            \pstart
            – Вы нас не подбросите до Соловца?
            \pend
            \pstart
            Второй, с рыжей бородой и без усов, тоже улыбался, выглядывая из-за его плеча. Положительно, это были приятные люди.
            \pend
            \pstart
            – Давайте садитесь, – сказал я. – Один вперед, другой назад, а то у меня там барахло, на заднем сиденье.
            \pend
            \pstart
            – Благодетель! – обрадованно произнес горбоносый, снял с плеча ружье и сел рядом со мной.
            \pend
            \pstart
            Бородатый, нерешительно заглядывая в заднюю дверцу, сказал:
            \pend
            \pstart
            – А можно я здесь немножко того?..
            \pend

            \pstart[
            \subsection*{Глава вторая}]
            \epigraph{\itshape 
            ...Опустевший дом превратился в логово лисиц и барсуков, и потому здесь могут появляться странные оборотни и призраки.}{А.  У э д а}
            \pend
            \pstart
            Я проснулся посреди ночи оттого, что в комнате разговаривали. Разговаривали двое, едва слышным шепотом. Голоса были очень похожи, но один был немного сдавленный и хрипловатый, а другой выдавал крайнее раздражение.
            \pend
            \pstart
            – Не хрипи, – шептал раздраженный. – Ты можешь не хрипеть?
            \pend
            \pstart
            – Могу, – отозвался сдавленный и заперхал.
            \pend
        \endnumbering
    \end{Leftside}
    \begin{Rightside}
    \selectlanguage{english}
        \beginnumbering
            \pstart[
            \chapter*{THE FIRST TALE}
            \section*{Run Around a Sofa}
            \subsection*{Chapter 1}]
            \epigraph{\itshape 
            Teacher: Children, write down the proposition: “The fish was sitting in a tree.”
            \newline 
            Pupil: But is it true that fish sit in trees?
            \newline 
            Teacher: Well… it was a crazy fish.}{School Joke}
            \pend
            \pstart
            I was approaching my destination. All around, pressing up against the very edge of the road, the green of the forest yielded now and then to a meadow overgrown with yellow sedge. The sun had been setting for an hour and still couldn’t make it, hanging low on the horizon. The car rolled along, crunching on a gravel surface. I steered around the bigger rocks, and each maneuver caused the empty canisters to rattle and clang in the trunk.
            \pend
            \pstart
            A couple of men came out of the woods on the right and stopped on the shoulder, looking in my direction. One of them raised his hand. I took my foot off the gas, scrutinizing the pair. They seemed to be hunters, young, and maybe a bit older than myself. Deciding I liked their looks, I stopped. The one who had raised his hand stuck his swarthy, hawk-nosed face through the window and asked, grinning,
            \pend
            \pstart 
            “Could you give us a lift to Solovetz?”
            \pend
            \pstart  
            The second man, with a reddish beard and without a moustache, peering over his shoulder, was also smiling. These were positively nice people.
            \pend
            \pstart
            “Sure thing. Get in,” I said. “One in the front and one in the back, “cause I have some junk on the rear seat.”
            \pend
            \pstart
            “A true philanthropist,” pronounced the hawk-nosed one joyfully as he slid the gun off his shoulder and sat down next to me.
            \pend
            \pstart
            The bearded one was looking through the rear door in a quandary of indecision and said, 
            \pend
            \pstart 
            “Eh, could you maybe move it a little?”
            \pend

            \pstart[
            \subsection*{Chapter 2}]
            \epigraph{\itshape 
            … The deserted house became the lair of foxes and badgers, and that is why weird spirits and shape-shifters can now appear here.}{A. Weda}
            \pend
            \pstart
            I woke up in the middle of the night because a conversation was going on in the room. Two voices were talking in a barely audible whisper. They were very similar, but one was a bit stifled and hoarse and the other betrayed an extreme irritation.
            \pend
            \pstart
            “Stop wheezing,” whispered the irritated one. “Can’t you do without it?”
            \pend
            \pstart
            “I can,” responded the stifled one, and began to hack.
            \pend
        \endnumbering
    \end{Rightside}
\end{pairs} 
\Columns

\end{sloppypar}
\end{document}
```

First chapter looks like this:
[image]

While the second - like this

[image]

Also, I am trying to make epigraphs body to be in italics but it does not seem to work. Where is the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two orders of problems.

First, `lmodern` is not compatible with Cyrillic fonts, remove it.

Second, most important: it seems that the language change is not honored by sectional titles. If I use

```
\chapter*{\foreignlanguage{russian}{ИСТОРИЯ ПЕРВАЯ}}
```

and similarly for `\section` and `\subsection`, the output is as expected, without errors.

You should also load `T1`.

[image]